# Mapping through object to render components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I am trying to create an application based on OpenWeatherMap API. For each day I intend to render a component that will present the data. I managed to filter out data for each day at midday and I can successfully log it into the console, however, I cannot map through this object and render it out as a component.

The code (in particular the render part is affected):

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    address: "City name",
    lat: null,
    lng: null,
    data: {}
  };

  onChange = address => this.setState({
    address
  });

  handleFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    geocodeByAddress(this.state.address)
      .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then(latLng => {
        const lat = latLng.lat;
        const lng = latLng.lng;
        this.setState({
          lat,
          lng
        });
        fetch(
            `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${lng}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`
          )
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            const dataWeather = data;
            this.setState({
              data: dataWeather.list
            });
          });
      })
      .catch(error => console.error("Error", error));
  };

  render() {
      const inputProps = {
        value: this.state.address,
        onChange: this.onChange
      };
      const weatherData = this.state.data;

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1> Weather application </h1>
            <span className="lead"> Get current weather of your location </span>
            <Form
              handleFormSubmit = { this.handleFormSubmit }
              inputProps = { inputProps }
            />
            <Weather />
          <ul>
            {
              [...weatherData].map((data) => {
                const myValues = data.dt_txt;
                const realHour = myValues.substring(10); 
                const hours = realHour.indexOf("12:00:00") > -1;
                console.log(hours); // true or false value
                hours === true ? console.log(data) : false;

                hours === true ? [...data].map((day, key) => console.log(day, key)) : false // This gives a true / false value
                hours === true ? [...data].map((day, key) => <WeatherTile date={data.dt_txt}/>) : false // This gives a true / false value

                })
              }
          </ul>
        </div>
          );
        }
      }

      export default App;
```

What it is logging into the console:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLMV8.png)

As mentioned in my comments in the code:

```
hours === true ? console.log(data) : false;
```

Actually logs the data for the correct day (so i.e. 24 april 12:00, 25 april 12:00 and so on).

However the line

```
hours === true ? [...data].map((day, key) => console.log(day, key)) : false
```

Gives a true/false response that actually affects the way it works (not actually rendering the component)

How can I actually render the component for each midday?

Comment: If you make a Codesandbox example I'll fix it for you.

Comment: From looking at your code though, I'm not sure you understand the ternary operator properly. `hours === true ? console.log(data) : false;` doesn't actually do anything if `hours` is not `true`. It's the equivalent of just writing `false;` on the line.

Comment: You'll need to add a `return`  to the last statement of the `[...weatherData].map` callback.

Comment: @Colin, the ternary operator is supposed to do the following: if the hour of data is 12:00 then render the component, if it's not - do nothing

Comment: @Oblosys, I tried to add it at the very beginning (so return hours === true ? [...data].map((day, key) => (<WeatherTile date={data.dt_txt}/>)) : false ) however it does not solve the issue

Comment: That's possible, but if you don't return anything from the callback, the `map` will create a list of `undefined`s and you won't see anything even if you solve the actual issue :-)

Comment: "The ternary operator is supposed to do the following: if the hour of data is 12:00 then render the component, if it's not - do nothing", sure, but that's not what you're doing at the moment.

Comment: @Colin at this stage I'm just trying to console log it, as it did not function and thanks to this I saw that it only logging true/false while the previous one, logging data is actually giving me the data I need and that I would like to iterate through. Any tips on how can I manage this?

Comment: I don't really understand. Make a Codesandbox example and I'll fix it for you.

Comment: Thank you, @Colin. Here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/384zl2zl06 this API key will be deleted afterward.

Comment: I can't get that to run, you're not passing anything to the `PlacesAutocomplete` component. Please give me something that works other than the error about not rendering you have above.

Comment: @Colin, is there any way you could explain what I should do instead of fixing the problem for me? I would like to learn from it as well.